# Не работает коллайдер с 2D объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть два объекта (спрайта) с коллайдерами:

1. Квадрат с `Box Collider 2D`
2. Персонаж (игрок) с `Capsule Collider 2D`

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

При попытки столкновения, персонаж проходит сквозь квадрат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Проверил функцией столкновения `OnTriggerEnter2D();` квадрат:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Dont touch me!");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблема в канвасе. Канвас для UI. Для геймплея и физики - мировое простанство.

Comment: Не совсем понял..

Comment: Судя по видео, ты хочешь использовать физику в канвасе. Т.е. игру, геймплейные механики, ты хочешь делать в канвасе. Во-первых, это неправильно. Во-вторых, возможно из-за канваса физика не работает, кроме триггеров (это предположение)

Comment: Убрал канвас, всё равно не помогает. Сейчас попробую другую сцену создам. Я думал канвас используется для того, чтобы все элементы подходили под любое разрешение экрана, а оказывается от для UI..

Comment: Вы были правы, спасибо.